# how can I set lists and also push lists in angular 4 firebase

Tags: angular, web-services, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I've a list of items ... and I want to push some values with fields from textboxes and set some values with default Values on adding an Item

I always use this

```
addResturant(resturant: resturant) {
  return this.resturants.push(resturant)
}
```

and the restaurant contains some details I want to

```
set(resturant.branches,'') also set(resturants.items,'')
```

where can I put them in the same method to be created on pressing on the btn save ?

here is the database architecture 
[image]

Comment: How is your data in firebase? can you show us some content to see the structure? I don't undertand precisly your problem. Can you do an example or add some code please

Comment: Well I want to make empty nodes called items and branches ... so it's the only way I knew to make an empty Node called items and called branches ... so I want on adding new restaurant .. items and branches nodes created with free values ... and the other restaurant keys and values push in the database normally like restaurantname , resturantdesc and so on. @Wandrille

Comment: and in your firebase database, for restaurant , is it a list with generated key?

Comment: yes it is fine to create a new restaurant with a generated key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better structure will be:

in your component:

```
constructor(private resturantService:ResturantService){}

yourPushButton(resturant){
   // I presume resturant is an object
   resturant['branches']='';
   resturant['items']='';
   this.resturantService.pushResturant(resturant)
}
```

And in your service ResturantService:

```
constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase){} <--- if you use angularFire2

pushResturant(resturant){
   const itemsRef = this.db.object('resturants/${resturant.name}')
   itemsRef.update(resturant)
}
```

Comment: oh it is not an object it's a list !

Comment: When you add a new resturant, this will be an object, not a list. You have a list of resturants. You want to add more than one resturant at a time?

Comment: ok great can u tell me how to get an Object ? I always use this to get a list.

Comment: this.resturants = this.af.list('/restaurants') as FirebaseListObservable<resturant[]>;

Comment: With this.resturants = this.af.list('/restaurants'), you get an array of object right? So I don't understand your problem. Edit your problem with the structure of your data in firebase. So everybody can help you

Comment: please check the db structure now

Comment: So now I understand. The key is your resturant name. See my Edit (don't use the type for the list but the on for the object)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156372/discussion-between-bishoy-ezzat-and-wandrille).